# org-mode datetree forward one day in the future

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

At work we do standups about what we did yesterday, I'm using `datetree` for my org-capture but the date recorded is by default today's date, I would like to change this so the date is of tomorrow instead of today.

Any pointers on how to change `datetree` default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the org-capture code, there's a `:default-time` property which by default uses the current time or the value of `org-overriding-default-time`. What the advice does is it shifts today's date by one day and assigns the new date to that variable, which is obviously a workaround so use it with caution:

```el
(advice-add 'org-capture :around
            (lambda (oldfun &rest args)
              (let ((org-overriding-default-time
                     (funcall
                      (lambda ()
                        (let ((day (string-to-number (format-time-string "%d")))
                              (month (string-to-number (format-time-string "%m")))
                              (year (string-to-number (format-time-string "%Y"))))
                          (encode-time 1 1 0 (1+ day) month year))))))
                (apply oldfun args))))
```

---

You can also find or create an entry with a future date using the `org-datetree-find-date-create` function. Note that 86400 is the number of seconds in one day, so what the `datetree-tomorrow` function does is it adds that number to the current time to get tomorrow's date. Now you should be able to use this function in your template without having to advice org-capture.

```el
(defun datetree-tomorrow ()
  (org-datetree-find-date-create
   (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute
    (time-to-days (time-add (current-time) (list 0 86400 0))))))

("key" "description" entry (file+function "path/to/file" datetree-tomorrow)
 "%?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also navigate to the day (tomorrow) in the Agenda view and press `k` for bringing up the capture templates. The date from the Agenda will be used then for the datetree.